# How to tell Gitbook where to store files locally?

Tags: gitbook

I just want to create a simple gitbook on my local drive, not attached to any remote repository. I went to File->Change Library Path... and pointed to the place where I want my files to go. When I create a new book, Gitbook puts some stuff in that library path that looks right: README.md, etc. But when I change README.md in Gitbook and save the file, it doesn't save to the README.md it created when I created the book. In fact I can't even figure out where it saved my changes, even after doing a find/grep on my entire hard drive.

***Edit:*** I need to know where it saves, so I can run the command-line gitbook to create a pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Which OS are you using?
On Windows, the default directory is C:\Users\username\GitBook

Answer (score 0):

I had troubles with this when I first started too.

Here is some background that may help you

- There are three flavors of gitbook: The online editor (storage is on Gitbook.com or Github), the offline editor (same storage + local at C:\Users\Documents\Gitbook), and the CLI toolchain (any storage you desire).
- If you talking about issuing commands, you want to install the toolchain
- If you are running Windows, I can't help, but when you switch to Ubuntu :) go to toolchain.gitbook.com to see the the instructions.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its weird that the changes are not immediately reflected in the physical file. I changed something and saved again, that actually made the first save visible. :D Try it once, this may work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Gitbook Editor works with git history only. So externally edited and not committed files in that folder will not be identified in the editor. However, when you save the files in gitbook editor, it creates a commit and then only it will be reflected in the physical drive location.

You can find more about the issue here: https://github.com/GitbookIO/feedback/issues/101

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no way to explicitly tell `GitBook` where to store files, however we use a simple workaround which allows us to use the `GitBook Editor` to edit a book in our own `git` repository but keep control of how and when we commit changes.

We have a `docs` directory in our project which contains the `gitbook` which is `symlinked` to the folder GitBook uses to store its own books. This directory has its own `.git` folder ignored from a parent directory as we don't need GitBooks commits.